# What to do about dupe answers?

Tags: discussion

Dupe questions I know what to do with.  Answers to dupe questions I know what to do with.  But when someone posts a lengthy answer that is a letter for letter dupe of one of their answers on a different question is there anything that should be done?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020219/1493294) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020433/1493294) are what make me bring this up.  They have other issues as well but I'm not asking about that.  I'm simply asking if copying an answer around like this is an issue on it's own.  If it's otherwise a valid answer is it fine?

Comment: After posting his answer on the first question, he then created a dupe question (plagiarizing the first one), then self-answered with his dupe answer.   Problematic.